# Using a token from 'new' action in 'create' action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-routing

What I'm trying to do is email someone a link where they can reply to a message, but obscuring the message_id with a token so that people can't just spam replies to any messages they like.

What I want is a path something like: `/reply/:message_reply_token/new`

That will generate the correct form with the previous message visible for the user to reply to using something like this:

```
@parent_message = Message.find_by_reply_token(params[:message_reply_token])
@reply_message = @parent_message.reply_messages.build
```

The problem I'm having is in my `create` action. How do I get that `:message_reply_token` back to the `create` action to actually create and save the new reply?

Comment: You can put it in hidden input in form.

Comment: Is that a "rails" way of doing it? I'm still very new to rails

Comment: It's perfectly ok to use this approach in Rails.

Comment: Would you mind adding it as an answer for me to accept, and could you put how to add it as a hidden field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could put it in hidden field in form:

```
<%= hidden_field_tag :message_reply_token, params[:message_reply_token] %>
```

and use it in `create` action via:

```
params[:message_reply_token]
```